How to silence warnings from 3rd party includefiles with Meson and GCC
It looks like meson is picking compiler flags from pkg-config and consequently setting include paths to dependencies using the -I flag. This leads to annoying warnings if you start turning on enough warnings.
Is there a way to work around this. I was thinking if gcc had some flag to consider header files under /usr to be system header anyway, but I didn't find such flag. Or if there's a meson-trick to make it use -isystem instead to point out the include path to (some) dependencies.

What kind of warnings are you getting? Can you post a few of them?

@Joel arith-conversion, conversion, old-style-cast, padded, useless-cast, zero-as-null-pointer-constant. Furthermore old-style-cast and useless-cast is tryggered during macro expansion as well.

Seems that you need to disable the warning -Wold-style-cast and others. For futher information see C++: Disable old style cast warnings in CMake. For other warnings you'll need to search about how to disable each one or update your code like suggested for warning: zero as null pointer constant while comparing iterators.

But that would silence the warnings globally which is less than ideal. The warnings are there for a reason an silencing them ought to be done quite selectively. I want to silence those arising from expansion of macros defined in 3rd party headers only.
